# Is there a way to inspect the query string run by asyncpg?

Tags: python, postgresql, asyncpg

When I use [asyncpg](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/index.html) to run a query on my database (and I have to run several queries),
I always split up things like this:

- the string of the query, with parameters placeholders:

  ```
  QUERY_1 = """
  UPDATE TABLE my_table 
  SET field_1 = $1
  WHERE field_id = $2;
  """
  ```
- a dictionary with the query parameters:

  ```
  query_params_dict = { 
      "field_1" : "value_1",
      "field_id" : "10"
  }
  ```
- and the function that will get the query string, replace the placeholders with the parameters values, run the query with [connection.execute](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html?highlight=connection%20execute#asyncpg.connection.Connection.execute), and manage the errors:

  ```
  async def run_query_1(query_params_dict):
      connection = await Utils.get_connection_to_db(**conf.asyncpg_db_conn) # custom function to open the connection to my db
      query = QUERY_1
      try:
          await connection.execute(
              query, query_params_dict["field_1"], int(query_params_dict["field_id"])
          )
          return None
      except (Exception, asyncpg.UniqueViolationError) as integrError:
          logger.error("Violated unique constraint: {}".format(integrError), exc_info=True)
          return "{}".format(integrError)
      except (Exception, asyncpg.ConnectionFailureError) as error:
          logger.error("Failed connection: {}".format(error), exc_info=True)
          return "{}".format(error)
      finally:
          if (connection):
              await Utils.close_connection(connection)
  ```

But the queries I have to run often require many mores parameters, so that I always make some mistake in assigning values to the variables,
so that the query fails/returns unwanted results,
and the only way I know to determine what is wrong with it, is to check carefully the value assigned to every parameter of `query_params_dict`.

This takes a lot of time.
Instead, I could understand quickly what is wrong by checking the query run by asyncpg.

So, **is there a way to inspect the query string run by asyncpg?**

I would expect a command of asyncpg taking the same arguments of `connection.execute` as input, and returning as output the string of the query filled up with parameters, without running any query on the database.
Let's suppose this command exists and is `connection.expected_query`, in my case it would work like this:

```
connection.expected_query(
                query, query_params_dict["field_1"], int(query_params_dict["field_id"])
>>>

"""
UPDATE TABLE my_table 
SET field_1 = 'value_1'
WHERE field_id = 10;
"""
```

Comment: Does `asyncpg` really let you pass the identifiers (like the table name) as a parameter like this?

Comment: Actually it does not, thanks! I have updated the question.

Comment: is there a way to print the executed query? query logging in asyncpg?